# What is the cipher principle?

Tags: algorithm, encoding

The table bellow displays the encoding of the numbers from 0 to 30. I need to decrypt the principle of encryption and then write a program in c or c++ which encodes a given series of natural numbers (input number will fit into 32-bit integer). What is the cipher principle?

```
0    .
1    ()
2    (())
3    (.())
4    ((()))
5    (..())
6    (()())
7    (...())
8    ((.()))
9    (.(()))
10   (().())
11   (....())
12   ((())())
13   (.....())
14   (()..())
15   (.()())
16   (((())))
17   (......())
18   (()(()))
19   (.......())
20   ((()).())
21   (.().())
22   (()...())
23   (........())
24   ((.())())
25   (..(()))
26   (()....())
27   (.(.()))
28   ((())..())
29   (.........())
30   (()()())
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please review the welcome tutorial for SO, and [How to ask...](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [how to ask homework questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions)

Answer (score 3):

Prime factorization.  The list is keyed by the ordering of primes.  The elements of a list, in order, denote 2, 3, 5, 7, ...

Parentheses at a given element denote that the prime is a factor; a dot shows that it's not.  Concatenated elements are multiplication of different numbers; nested elements are multiplication by that prime.  Thus ...

```
(()) first element is (), for 2.
(.()) second element is (), for 3.
((())) first element is (()); the nesting denotes raising to a power.  They're both 2, so we get 2^2, or 4.
((.())) is 2^3, or 8.
(((()))) is 2^4, or 16.

(()()) is 2*3, or 6.
```

Does that get you moving?